# SELECT query does not work when converted to VBA - invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been struggling with SQL statement when converted to VBA. Basically, I wish to add something to it before executing (which shouldn't be a problem). However, when I try to run it before changes, VBA does not recognize it as a valid SQL statement. Despite trying to add/remove brackets and any other special character, it still does not work. Please note, that it works perfectly when run as a query. Please see the string below:

```
SQLstr = "SELECT SourceData.[Fiscal Year], SourceData.[Fiscal Quarter ID], " _
& "SourceData.[Transaction Date], SourceData.[Sales Order Number], SourceData.[Activated?], " _
& "SourceData.[Product ID], SourceData.[Bookings Quantity], SourceData.[Term Length], " _
& "SourceData.[Estimated Expiring Quarter], SourceData.[End Customer Company Name], " _
& "SourceData.[Sold To Company Name] " _
& "FROM SourceData, finalCust, finalPart " _
& "WHERE (((SourceData.[End Customer Company Name]) Like finalCust.[FinalList]) " _
& "And ((SourceData.[Sold To Company Name]) Like finalPart.[FinalList]))"
```

The code is 'pure' SQL into VBA, without any amendments but I don't want to mislead.

Here's an error message:

```
Run-time error '2342':
A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.
```

Which I would consider as unreadable SQL statement for VBA.

Comment: can you post the whole error please

Comment: You have included three tables, but no relationship (/JOINS) between them. Why? Could possibly be a reason for your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is misleading.  The real problem is that `DoCmd.RunSQL` is intended for "action" queries: `UPDATE`; `INSERT`; `DELETE`; etc.

It will not accept a plain `SELECT` query.  For example, this simple `SELECT` query gives me that same *"A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement"* message from `DoCmd.RunSQL`:

```sql
Dim SQLstr As String
SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM tblFoo;"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstr
```

However, `DoCmd.RunSQL` executes this valid `UPDATE` statement without error:

```sql
SQLstr = "UPDATE tblFoo SET long_text='bar' WHERE id=1;"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstr
```

You need a different method to use your `SELECT` query.  And the choice of method depends on what you want to do with the results returned by the query.

Comment: You will need to use OpenRecordset to run the query and access the results.