# SQL Syntax for VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have been working on a simple VBA function to check what type of User the current user is and opening the appropriate form for them at startup of my Access db. I have already defined a GetWindowsUserName function to get the username correctly as seen when I do Debug.Print, I used the following code:

```
Public Function CheckUser()
Dim UserName As String
Dim SQLType As String
UserName = UserNameWindows()
SQLType = "SELECT tbl_Users.[UserType] FROM tbl_Users WHERE tbl_Users.[SOEID]='" & UserName & "';"
Debug.Print SQLType
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLType
If SQLType = "Admin" Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_AdminLandingPage"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Loading"
Else
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_LandingPage"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Loading"
End If
End Function
```

Debug.Print results in the following for the SQL Statement, I also ran it in Access's SQL View and it runs just fine:

`SELECT tbl_Users.[UserType] FROM tbl_Users WHERE tbl_Users.[SOEID]='GS429';`

When I try to run the function however, it results in your typical "A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement."

Thoughts? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: same error unfortunately. :(

Comment: `RunSQL` is not for `select` queries. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421873/select-query-does-not-work-when-converted-to-vba-invalid-sql-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
SQLType = "SELECT tbl_Users.[UserType] FROM tbl_Users WHERE tbl_Users.[SOEID]='" & UserName & "';"
Debug.Print SQLType
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLType
```

With this:

```
SQLType=DLookup("UserType","tbl_Users","SOEID='" & UserName & "'")
```

Comment: I don't think you need bother with the *UserName* variable.  Just use the function which supplies that variable's value: `DLookup("UserType","tbl_Users","SOEID=UserNameWindows()")`

Answer (score 2):

`DoCmd.RunSQL` only works for "action" queries like `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`. It doesn't work with a standard `SELECT`. You could open up a connection and use that to populate a `RecordSet`.

See this link: [VBA New Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313899/vba-new-database-connection)