# INNER JOIN VBA Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to do a dynamic SQL statement in which the command will add the field "Drawn" in a certain area of the depending on the value of j. This is because there are several instances where the field "Rev" in table "Revision" appears. I created this statement in the query design but only to update a specific field in the table, not dependent on my counter j. I'm getting 'JOIN expression not supported'. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
Select Case selection(n)
Case "A"
    j = 1
Case "B"
    j = 2
Case "0"
    j = 3
Case "1"
    j = 4
Case "2"
    j = 5
End Select

With rs
    While Not .EOF
          DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT Area.Drawn " & _
                                 "FROM (Revision INNER JOIN RevDesc ON Revision.Rev" & j & " = RevDesc.Rev) " & _
                                 "INNER JOIN Area ON Revision.LineNumber = ArealineNmuber ;"
.MoveNext   
wend 
end with
```

Comment: @David, I fixed the problem, Area was a table and lineNumber a field. So I added the "." between them. However, now I get 'A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement'

Comment: Typing the error message into Google is always a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27425050/328193

Comment: @David is there no way to use a SELECT clause like the one I have with a command similar to the runSQL?

Comment: Well, it's not really clear what you're trying to do here.  You're attempting to execute a `SELECT` without reading the results or doing anything with them.  Why select data from a database if you're not going to use that data?

Comment: how looks Update comand that you try run?

Comment: @AdamSilenko What I did is creaty a query design and adapted the SQL syntax to VB. With the difference that I need to loop through one field depending on a certain variable. So it would be something like this:

`DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ([RevDesc] " & _
                                    "INNER JOIN [Revision] ON [RevDesc]![Rev] = [Revision]![Rev" & j & "]) " & _
                                    "INNER JOIN Area ON [Revision]![LineNumber] = [Area]![LineNumber] " & _
                                    "SET [Revision]![Drawn" & j & "] = [Area]![Drawn];" `

Comment: @David I'm trying to fetch the value of a field. I've corrected it and use an update with inner joins as shown above. however, I'm having problems getting it to work. I don't know if it's an issue with the way i'm using my dynamic variable j. I'm still getting the error 3296 (Join expression not supported)

Comment: @JesusEspiga: The code still has the same typo from yesterday... `ArealineNmuber`

Comment: @David When I meant above, I was referring to the comment I left to AdamSilenko. Can you see the comment? Or do you want me to modify it in the question section?

Comment: @JesusEspiga: Code in comments is notoriously difficult to follow.  Also, if the error is coming from the database engine, then as a debugging step you're going to want to examine what the runtime query actually being executed is.  Which means replacing those concatenated variables with the actual values being used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you looking for method like [OpenRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)...
Lopping Recordset use result fields to generate simple `Update` with you can run by RunSQL method.

EDIT:
example update:

```
UPDATE [Revision] 
SET [Drawn] = (SELECT [Drawn] FROM [Area] WHERE [Area].[LineNumber] = [Revision].[LineNumber] )
WHERE Exists(SELECT 1 FROM [RevDesc] 
  WHERE [RevDesc].[Rev] = [Revision].[Rev]);
```