# MS Access - Writing SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

**BACKGROUND**

Develop a MS Access module that executes SQL code when onClick() event triggered.

**CODE**

```
Dim sqlString As String

sqlString = "SELECT [Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[COMPANY ID], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[COMPANY NAME], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].ITEM, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].STYLE, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].DESCRIPTION, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[SALE PRICE], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[ON-HAND QTY], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[FORECAST QTY], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[MaxOfLATEST PO DATE] " _
    & "FROM [Table - Active Product Catalog] " _
    & "LEFT JOIN [Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs] " _
        & "ON [Table - Active Product Catalog].STYLE = [Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].STYLE " _
    & "GROUP BY [Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[COMPANY ID], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[COMPANY NAME] , " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].Item, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].Style, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].Description, " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[SALE PRICE], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[ON-HAND QTY], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[FORECAST QTY], " _
        & "[Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[MaxOfLATEST PO DATE]" _
    & "HAVING ((([Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs].[COMPANY NAME]) Like ' * ' & [Enter Company Name:] & ' * '));"


DoCmd.RunSQL sqlString
```

**ERROR**

> Run-time error '2342': A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.

**QUESTION(S)**

1. I've followed the following [tutorial](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm) but receive an error. It appears that the RunSQL command isn't recognizing sqlString as a SQL command. However, I am positive that the SQL statement runs correctly in MS Access. Any ideas?
2. On the last line of the SQL statement, I have a MsgBox prompt ("`[Enter Company Name:]`"). I am not quite sure if this is throwing off the SQL statement but, as stated before, the syntax runs in MS Access; even if I replace the prompt with a hard-coded value, I receive the same error message.

*NOTE: I'll most likely create an `inputBox` that asks for the `company name` and then place the variable within the last line of the SQL statement.*

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421873/select-query-does-not-work-when-converted-to-vba-invalid-sql-statement

Comment: Consider using table aliases in your SQL (`SELECT Summary.[COMPANY ID] FROM [Table - Summary - All Item Forecasts, Sales, and POs] AS Summary`) ; it'll make your statements both shorter and easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the DoCmd.RunSQL [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx), it is used to run an "action query". That is, the *SQLStatement* is

> A string expression that's a valid SQL statement for an action query or a data-definition query. It uses an INSERT INTO, DELETE, SELECT...INTO, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE INDEX, or DROP INDEX statement.

Note that the above list includes `SELECT...INTO` but not a plain `SELECT`. To execute a plain `SELECT` and return a recordset you need to do something like

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset(sqlString, dbOpenSnapshot)
' loop through the Recordset contents
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, in your last 2 lines you're missing the space between ...[MaxOfLATEST PO DATE] and HAVING. It will fall over when it tries to run that as SQL.
I've hit this myself a few times, as I'm very new to VBA - I always put a debug.print SQLstring after the run command as it's easier to find these missing spaces etc in the Immediate window.

HTH, Jenny